# "to fart" in child language

Tags: word-choice

What is the appropriate word for "to fart" regarding babies?

As "to fart" is declared as *impolite* in the most dictionaries there needs to be another word for it regarding babies? Like "pupsen" vs. "furzen" in German.

Comment: Some friends taught their children the term "bottom burp". I don't know how common it is (UK).

Comment: @Mick [reasonably common](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bottom-Burps-Other-Purple-Ronnies/dp/075227242X)

Comment: I wouldn't really say that the word is "impolite", though some dictionaries do say that - [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fart) marks it as "very informal", which I believe is closer to the mark. Note that [BBC News](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=XV8EWpGvN4jRsAfskpuwDQ&btnG=Search&q=site%3Anews.bbc.co.uk+fart) seems to use the word reasonably often, even in headlines, which would be very unlikely if the word were really offensive in any way. (There may be a difference in perception between UK/US; I couldn't comment on that.)

Comment: Soft words for children are nice, but they can be problematic.   My parents wouldn't say the word Sh*t or Crap or Poop, so I was raised calling a number 2 a whiff and I thought everyone called it that.   When I got to summer-camp I was speaking a different language than everyone else because my parents didn't like some words and that caused some laughter.

Comment: @psmears I think it is certainly considered a mildly impolite term.

Comment: Yeah, my mother used to refer to farting as "making a rude smell".  When I started school, I was unaware that there was any other term for it.  I've never heard anyone outside my immediate family use this expression.  So for goodness sake, call a fart a fart, and that way your children are sure to be understood.

Comment: A generally polite way of saying "it", should be understood by all, and is certainly _child friendly_, but maybe not "child language"(?) is "let one go". As in "Sorry, I let one go.", "Oooh, did you let one go?", "I wouldn't go in there, he just let one go!". Reference: https://youtu.be/TXGNuJ6wIes

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In AmE, if you want another word to refer to a child farting, then you could use *toot* or *poot*. I could not quickly find a reputable dictionary entry for this particular usage of *toot*, but it is simply an extension of its dictionary meaning (OALD):

> [toot](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/toot)
>   A short, sharp sound made by a horn, trumpet, or similar instrument.

There is an entry for [*poot*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/poot) in the OALD

> US
>   informal
>   Break wind.
>   ‘somebody just pooted’

There are two from Wiktionary: [toot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toot), [poot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poot)

For context, there are many  euphemisms for *fart*. "Breaking wind" as used above is one. Another is *passing gas* (TFD):

> [pass gas](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+gas)
>   Euph. to release intestinal gas through the anus. *Someone on the bus had passed gas. It smelled awful. Something I ate at lunch made me pass gas all afternoon.*

This can apply to any person.

Finally, the formal word is [flatulence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flatulence) (M-W):

> flatus expelled through the anus

Comment: +1 See also *[Beans, beans, the Musical Fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beans,_Beans,_the_Musical_Fruit)* (0:

Comment: @CowperKettle Oh, yeah. I forgot about that, which reminds of [the Simpsons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymgOhE0mNWE).

Comment: My wife often uses the phrase "tooty booty" when she's feeling *gassy*.

Comment: +1 I would say that "toot" is slightly more polite than "poot", probably because it does have a non-flatulence-related meaning.

Comment: Is "poot" regional? I've never heard it before.

Comment: "Break wind" is also appropriate in Britain and Ireland - you could include it in your answer

Comment: "Toot" was the first thing to occur to me.  It's what my 3-year-old calls it.  (I'm in the USA)

Comment: With my godson it was "poopsonhausen" :-)

Comment: What is "AmE"? Google search don't give any meaningful results. If it's some fancy English acronym, I'm afraid many users just don't understand what it is, since not everyone here are native English speakers.

Comment: @ShadowWizard **Am**erican **E**nglish. It's commonly used here on ELL. There is a brief list on ELL Meta [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/list-of-common-symbols-and-abbreviations/708#708).

Answer (score 36):

In England a trump is wind that comes out of an arse (and has been for decades to my own personal knowledge so has not arisen from recent world events).

Comment: +1 - see also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264355/in-what-english-speaking-communities-does-trump-refer-to-the-breaking-of-wind

Comment: It's a term (much) more common in the north of England I believe.

Answer (score 7):

My favourite is from Blackadder:

> NURSIE: ...and letting off such great and fruit-some *flappy woof-woofs!* One can scarcely...one can't believe one's tiny nosy!
>
> *-- [Blackadder 2 - "Beer"](http://www.clarkymkweb.co.uk/mktheatreofcomedy/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/BA2_AuditionPiece17.pdf)*

Although, this is not a commonly used phrase, except by fans of Blackadder.

Comment: It's worth noting (since this is a site for learners of English) that, entertaining though it is, this is not really a standard English phrase!

Answer (score 7):

You could consider the verb ***to parp***
 ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parp)).

Its original and standard meaning is "a honking sound", like the sound made by an old rubber car or bicycle horn.  The word is [onomatopoeic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) (it sounds like what it describes).

But in the right context people will recognise that you are talking about the sound the baby made, or indeed the entire farting behaviour in which the baby engaged.

The word itself is not considered impolite, although the topic still might not be considered tasteful in all forms of company.

I believe it would also be acceptable to use the noun ***a parp*** although you might not find that in frequent use.

Answer (score 3):

My child's nursery (in London) called them "windypops". We still use it. I'm not sure how common it is, but I think  in context it's fairly obvious to a native speaker.

Comment: Lovely! Of course, most British kids will know the term [*whizzpopper*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmPvrlqhI1U), coined by Roald Dahl.

Answer (score 3):

My mother used **'blowing off'** as a euphemism for fart.

Comment: We used that too when I was a kid. When I heard the expression "to blow someone off", meaning to be dismissive of someone, that amused my juvenile mind because I pictured someone farting on someone.

Answer (score 1):

In our family, they were called a 'scuse', because we had to say 'excuse me' after doing one (as young children, not as babies). Dictionary.com records 'scuse' as a general abbreviation for 'excuse', but I cannot find any reference to 'a scuse' anywhere on the internet (so far).